# Как получить данные из Post

Tags: django

Имеется такой код:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MainFormView(DataMixin, FormView):
form_class = MainForm
template_name = 'sitee/index.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['menu_selected'] = 'home'
    c_def = self.get_user_context(title="Главная")
    return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))

def form_valid(self, form):
    # print(POST)
    #context['result'] = POST['title']
    return redirect('home')

#index.html
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-error">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
<input id="title" name="title" type="text"/>
<input id="datetime" name="datetime" type="text"/>
    <label for="id_groups_0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups" value="0" id="id_groups_0">
        Группа 2
    </label>
    <label for="id_groups_1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups" value="0" id="id_groups_1">
        Группа 1
    </label>
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
{{result}}
```

При попадании на страницу home появляется эта форма. Как после нажатия на "Отправить", вывести данные из post запроса, добавить в контекст значение из post['title'] и вывести на страницу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Generic Views есть методы `get` и `post`. Оба вызывают `self.get_context_data()`. Переопределяете его, получаете данные `POST` запроса из `self.request.POST` и делайте что хотите.

Примитивный пример

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    cd = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    if 'POST' in self.request.method:
         cd['post_data'] = post_data = request.POST  # Какой то из подтипов dict, неизменяемый

         cd['post_title'] = post_data.get('title')

    return cd
```

Если ответ не помог, значит плохо пояснили, что требуется

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что нужно! Осталось разобраться, как сделать тоже самое только без перезагрузки страницы =)

Comment: Лучше с редиректом. Для этого передавайте нужные данные в GET параметрах, либо сохраняйте в сессию